# Entity Framework Nested Query Select() Problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am new to the entity framework and trying to get data using foreign key from `Answers` table but I am getting error

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case'
>   Operation2='Collect'

`p.Answers.Count()` or `p.Answers.SingleOrDefault().correct_answer`as string works fine but `p.Answers.Select(c => c.correct_answer).ToList()` throwing `nested query error`

I want to keep it in one query because there could be thousands of questions so I don't want to check answers to the separate queries. Following is my code.

```
return db.Questions.Where(p => p.q_id == q_id).Select(p => new QuestionViewModel
{
   q_id = p.q_id,
   q_text = p.q_text,
   q_answer = p.Answers.Count() > 0 ? p.Answers.Select(c => c.correct_answer).ToList() : null
}).OrderBy(x => x.q_id).ToList();
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public long q_id { get; set; }
    public string q_text { get; set; }
    public List<string> q_answer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is telling you that EF does not support conditional subquery, implied by expressions like this:

```
p.Answers.Count() > 0 ? p.Answers.Select(c => c.correct_answer).ToList() : null
```

So simply remove the conditional operator:

```
q_answer = p.Answers.Select(c => c.correct_answer).ToList()
```

In case there are no related answers for question, `q_answer` will be populated with *empty* list rather than `null`, which is the normal (expected) behavior for collection type objects.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know EF doesn't support conditional subquery. Without conditional subquery, it's working fine. Thanks again