# The nested Query is not supported. operation 1='Case' Operation2='Collect'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on dot net application, and making that query in which i have to use nested condition inside select statement. I am not able to find any solution. Please if any one can help.

```
(from c in db.Tblcases

    select new {
    Name = c.Name,
    Make = c.Make,
    Model = (c.CaseType == 1 ? (from df in db.TblData where df.Id = c.RefId select Name):
    c.CaseType == 2 ? (from mf in db.TblMobile where mf.Id = c.RefId select Name):
    c.CaseType == 3 ? (from mis in db.TblMis where mis.Id = c.RefId select Name):
    null
    }).ToList()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Nested Query Select() Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533104/entity-framework-nested-query-select-problem)